# Replacing Huge Pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, embedded, renesas-rx

I am currently working on a project where I need to replace the existing microcontroller, which belongs to the M16C family, with a new microcontroller from the RX family. In the old code for the M16C microcontroller, I have the following memory qualifier defined:

```c
#define CHIPDATA huge

extern byte CHIPDATA Mode4Reg[1];
```

My goal is to transition to the RX family while retaining the use of the CHIPDATA attribute. However, the "huge" memory qualifier is not directly applicable to the RX family, and I need to adapt it for the new environment.

Could you please provide guidance on how to replace the "huge" memory qualifier with an appropriate equivalent for the RX family microcontroller? I want to preserve the use of CHIPDATA in the code.

I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```c
#pragma section = "MyExternalMemorySection"

#define CHIPDATA __root
```

Comment: Isn't "huge" the non-standard keyword for extended addressing? I.e. many 16 bitters want a bigger address space than 64kib and then they invent something like 24/32 bit addressing. Normally called `far` but it's not standardized. If that is true, then you don't need to worry about it on a pure 32 bit data 32 bit address MCU - it fills no purpose there.

Comment: Please clarify which compiler the original code base used. The answer to the question can doubt be found in that compiler manual. I peeked at some M16C compiler manual from Renesas but it only mentioned near/far.

Comment: IAR'd compiler defines `__huge` as a legacy alias for `__data20` to represent a 20 bit data address pointer.  Is perhaps `huge` an alias for `__huge` or are you using some other compiler.

Comment: The thing you "tried" seems to be semantically different from what `huge` does.  What exactly are you trying to do?  Seems like you are trying to locate data in a specific section.  Looks like an X-Y problem that you are conflating two different concepts.  I suggest you forget `huge` and M16C and just ask a question about what you want to achieve on the new platform.  For which you _must_ specify the toolchain.

Comment: The pragma will apply to subsequent data declarations, not to the macro.  If `#pragma section` is the only way of locating data in your toolchain, you cannot do that with a qualifier macro applied as in your existing code.  For that you would need the gcc-like `__attribute__` extension.  Most likely the data does not need specific location in any event.

Answer (score 1):

M16C has different memory models for 13, 16 and 20 bit addressing. RX is a 32 bit Harvard Architecture MCU and the same memory models do not apply.  You most likely need to do nothing special for RX addresses and can simply define an empty macro:

```
#define CHIPDATA
```

If you want to be able to build the same codebase cross platform then:

```c
#if defined __M16C__
    #define CHIPDATA huge
#else
    #define CHIPDATA
#endif
```

However it seems that you are in fact trying to use the `CHIPDATA` modifier for a different purpose on the new platform, making this an X-Y problem.  Ask a new question about how to define a macro to locate specific data to a linker section (if that is what you are trying to do).  You can then call that macro `CHIPDATA` should you choose for re-usability of existing code.  The means will necessarily be toolchain specific, so you need to specify.   Whether such a macro would be valid as a prefix to the declaration rather then a suffix may be an issue.  It may not be possible to achieve what you want, but until it is clear what it is you do want, it is hard to tell.